# What do the result columns of a Sqlite explain query mean?

Tags: sqlite, android-sqlite

When executing "explain select..." on Sqlite, the execution plan is returned as a result. What do the columns mean?

The documentation simply says that they columns may change with each release. https://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html

Example:

```
addr| opcode| p1| p2| p3| p4| p5| comment
0| Init| 0| 15| 0| | 00| null
1| OpenRead| 0| 5| 0| 7| 00| null
2| Variable| 1| 1| 0| | 00| null
3| SeekRowid| 0| 14| 1| | 00| null
4| Copy| 1| 2| 0| | 00| null
```

Answer (score 0):

This other part of the Sqlite documentation suggests that they are operands of the Sqlite bytecode engine. I had been hoping that they were time estimates for the execution time.

"Each instruction has an opcode and five operands named P1, P2 P3, P4, and P5."

https://www.sqlite.org/opcode.html